# Disconnect button

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to create a button that allows me to **disconnect the user**, i have searched and found that the module of type "connexion" is what i need, but it doesnt work for me, it gives me an error.

so what i want to know is how can i create a button with php/html that disconnect the user?
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Why not simply use Joomla's Login module? When the user is logged in, it will provide a button allowing them to logout

Comment: It doesnt work for me, i clic create and it keeps loading and loading with no result.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a simple logout-link like this:

```
<?php 
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $userToken = JSession::getFormToken();
    if (!$user->guest) : ?>
        <a href="index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&<?php echo $userToken; ?>=1" class="btn">Log out</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The <kbd>Log out</kbd> button will only be visible to logged-in users, and when clicked the user will be logged out instantly. If you also want to show a <kbd>Login</kbd> button, you can modify the PHP if/else statement and display a link to the login page (`index.php?option=com_users&view=login`) for guests.

```
<?php 
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $userToken = JSession::getFormToken();
    if ($user->guest) : ?>
        <a href="index.php?option=com_users&view=login" class="btn">Log in</a>
<?php else: ?>
        <a href="index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&<?php echo $userToken; ?>=1" class="btn">Log out</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The combination of PHP and HTML is necessary because we need to get the *user token*, without it the link will fail.

### Usage:

The code can be used in several ways:

1. **Download from GitHub**
   This module is available on GitHub as an installable Joomla module: https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange/loginButton
2. **Custom HTML**
   Some Custom HTML modules accept PHP code (the one included in Joomla by default does not). I recommend [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-html-advanced). Just paste the code and publish the module wherever you want the button to show up. Remember you can also place a module anywhere using `{loadposition YourModulePosition}`.
3. **Sourcerer**
   You can add PHP code anywhere using NoNumbers [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer).

   ```
   {source}
   <?php 
       $user = JFactory::getUser();
       $userToken = JSession::getFormToken();
       if (!$user->guest) : ?>
           <a href="index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&<?php echo $userToken; ?>=1" class="btn">Log out</a>
   <?php endif; ?>
   {/source}
   ```
4. **Build a module**
   You can build your own module, it's easier than it sounds. A basic tutorial can be found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module).
5. **Add to your template**
   You can also paste the code directly into your Joomla template, usually `ROOT\templates\YOURTEMPLATE\index.php`. This is the least flexible solution, but might be a quick solution depending on how your template is configured.

Comment: Where do i put this code? is there any way to combine it with a html code?

Comment: @zenami please see my updated answer :)